# Mingw gcc, "-shared -static" passing together

Tags: gcc, static, mingw, ld, shared

When studying Scintilla's [makefile](https://github.com/mirror/scintilla/blob/719b774d9c37224f6d2e83d64fcc259c9ef67b11/win32/makefile#L41) for MinGW under windows, I noticed that it is passing *`-shared`* and *`-static`* together as `LDFLAGS` to gcc.

> `LDFLAGS=-shared -static -mwindows $(LDMINGW)`

I googled, and only find some information from clang:    https://reviews.llvm.org/D43811

> [MinGW, CrossWindows] Allow passing -static together with -shared
>   `In these combinations, link a DLL as usual, but pass -Bstatic instead of -Bdynamic to indicate prefering static libraries.`

My question is: *Would GCC do the same?*
I haven't find any proof yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass both `-static` and `-shared` in a GCC linkage.  Their
combined effect is the same as you found described in your llvm link,
and this has always been the case for GCC.

`-shared` directs a GCC linkage to produce a shared library rather than a program,
which it achieves by passing on the option `-shared` to its invocation of
the linker.

`-static` directs a GCC linkage to ignore shared libraries when resolving
input library options `-lname`. By default `-lname` would be resolved by
searching the specified or default linker search directories for either
the shared library `libname.so` (on Windows, `[lib]name.dll`)
or the static library `libname.a` (on Windows also `[lib]name.lib`) and to prefer
the shared library if both of them are found in the same directory. `-static`
simply excludes all shared libraries from the search. GCC achieves this by passing the option `-Bstatic`
through to its invocation of the linker at a position in the generated linker
commandline that precedes all of the `-lname` options.

The [GNU linker documentation of `-Bstatic`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html) is explicit
that this option is consistent with `-shared` and that the effect is to produce a shared library
all of whose dependent libraries have been statically resolved.

> -Bstatic
>
> -dn
>
> -non_shared
>
> -static
>
> Do not link against shared libraries. This is only meaningful on platforms for which shared libraries are supported.
>   The different variants of this option are for compatibility with various systems. You may use this option multiple times on the command line:
>   it affects library searching for -l options which follow it. This option also implies --unresolved-symbols=report-all.
>   **This option can be used with -shared. Doing so means that a shared library is being created but that all of the library’s external references must be resolved by pulling in entries from static libraries.**

(emphasis mine).

Although static linkage of shared library is in principle just a linkage restricted
in the same way as static linkage of a program, in practice it frequently encounters
a snag on Unix and Linux because all the object code linked into an ELF shared library
`libname.so` must be [Position Independent Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code),
as produced by the GCC compilation option `-fPIC`, whereas object files that are destined to be
archived in static libraries are customarily not compiled with `-fPIC`. Linkages using
`-shared ... -static` are thus apt to fail because necessary static libraries contain
non-PIC object files.

You do not have this worry with GCC on Windows, however, because there
is no such distinction as PIC v. non-PIC in Windows [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)
object code.